# Error when running ghost docker image second time

Tags: docker, ghost-blog, ghost

I can run docker container with ghost with this command (https://hub.docker.com/_/ghost/):

```
docker run -ti -v /tmp/data:/var/lib/ghost/content -p2368:2368 ghost
```

But only when `/tmp/data` is empty. If I try to stop this container with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and run it again, it fails with this error:

```
docker run -ti -v /tmp/data:/var/lib/ghost/content -p2368:2368 ghost
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/ghost/content/themes/casper': No such file or directory
```

I need to store ghost's data outside container and this is the way based on [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/ghost/). Am I missing something?

I'm trying this on Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem when running ghost under Docker for Mac.
I would suggest to create docker volume for your data, rather than mounting direct folder. There seems to be a problem with resolving symlinks.

`docker volume create ghost-data`
`docker run -it --mount source=ghost-data,target=/var/lib/ghost/content -p 2368:2368 ghost`

Answer (score -1):

i had this problem before but when i pull the latest version (docker pull ghost:latest) again everything work fine,,, i guess the chown on the ghost image Dockerfile made the ownership error....